# Is there a way to debug HTTP 500 Error Over ASP Classic Page?

Tags: asp-classic, http-status-code-404

My website is working fine but few pages are giving this odd error. You can check out here http://thevnsf.org/admin/EditStaff.asp

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-a-500-internal-server-error-for-all-asp-errors.html